# HTML Form Two Different Submit Buttons and Two Different Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

What is the best way to have an HTML form with two submit buttons and have them both do two different functions without using inline JavaScript? I can use Jquery so doing `$('#id').submit(function (event) {});` would be fine. Thanks.

Comment: what is the issue? it seems like you already answered yourself. just use jquery for it and have different identifiers for each submit button

Comment: you don't even need forms. You can use click functions if you are planning to use ajax

Answer (score 0):

Don't make them `<input type="submit">`, make them `<input type="button">`.

If you are doing a basic `HTTP POST`, then add a click event that will

1. change the `action` on the form
2. call `submit()` on the form.

If you're submitting via Ajax, the click events will just manage the `$.post()` process for each button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting the form data to the next page you could detect which button is clicked on, and assign  a value to each button such as "button 1" value=1 and "button 2" value= 2.  Then execute different functions on the page based on which button is clicked.  Here is a similar question:

[How do I use two submit buttons, and differentiate between which one was used to submit the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929471/how-do-i-use-two-submit-buttons-and-differentiate-between-which-one-was-used-to)