# Problem with two submit buttons and form on PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with Submit buttons.
I want to make a system like auto-alert subscribe.

But my second button with Subscribe is reddirect on the first page for purchase.php 
I tried to use formation in the second button

I know the problem is form action bcs i close after php cod, but i tried all option and i don't have any ideea.

If you have any suggestion without my system subscribe i listen.
Thank you for help.

```
<?php
$error_code = "if (this.src != 'assets/default-product.png') this.src = 'assets/default-product.png';";
?>
<img class="no-drag product-image" src="<?php echo $product_image; ?>" onerror="<?php echo $error_code; ?>">
<h1 style="font-size: 25px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 20px;"><?php echo $product_name; ?></h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">Region: <?php echo $product_region_name; ?></h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">Type: <?php echo $product_type_name; ?></h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">Status: <?php echo $product_status_name; ?></h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">Categories: <?php echo $product_categories_name; ?> Champions</h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">Current Rank: <?php echo $product_ranked_name; ?></h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">Last Check: <?php echo $last_checked; ?></h1>
<form action="purchase.php" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="post_product_id" id="post_product_id" value="<?php echo $post_product_id; ?>"/>
<?php

    if($total_product_stock == "0") {

        echo '<h1 style="font-size: 40px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">There are currently  Out of Stock </h1>';
        echo '<p></p><br>';
        echo '<h1 style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">Alert Stock Refill</h1>';
        echo '<input type="email" name = "email"style= "width: 35%; text-align: center;"placeholder="Enter your email"required></p><br>';
        echo '<button style="width: 20%;" type="submit2" value="submit2">Subscribe</button>';//END IF TOTAL STOCK IS 0
        if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) { // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
            $product_id = $post_product_id;
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            if ($email != '') {
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into notif_stock(product_id, email_contact)
                            values ('$product_id','$email')");
                echo "<br/><br/><span>Success Subscribed</span>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<br/><br/><span>Unsubscribed</span>";

        }
    }
    else{
        echo '';
        echo ' <label for="requested_quantity">Quantity</label><br>';
        echo '<input type="number" style="width: 125px;" class="form-control" name="requested_quantity" id="requested_quantity" min="1" max='.$total_product_stock.'" value="1"><br><br>';
        echo '<p>There are currently '.$total_product_stock.' accounts in stock</p><br>';
        echo '<button type="submit" name="buy" id="submit" value="buy">€'.$product_price.' each</button>';
        echo '';
    }//END ELSE

?>
</form>
    <a href="index.php"><button>Back to Home</button></a>
</div>
</div></center>
<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways of making this work.

For example [JS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691653/multiple-submit-buttons-php-different-actions).

Or:
[Naming your submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929513/7158959).

Or: [using HTML5 input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28528359/7158959).

Also check linked and related topics on this links mentioned above for more info.

As you can see plenty of solutions here on SO for you to find and choose from.
When you do your reading and chose one and have trouble implementing feel free to ask for help.

Good luck.

PS: no such thing as `type="submit2"`